# How many instances of a partial date (month & day) appear in a range, and its day of the week

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In Java, how would I go about constructing a utility that would take a range of dates (start and end date) and then would see how many times a given partial date ( the month and day-of-month) appears in that range, and will add an entry to a list for each match.

In my instance, I want to give it a range of say 5 years - starting Jan 1st 2014 and going to Dec 31st 2019. My check date is the 2nd August. I want the method to return the full information about each match of any August 2 of any year in the range. So for 2014 is will return Saturday 2nd August 2014, then Sunday 2nd August 2015 etc and so on.

I've been trying to get something working so far with Joda Time and the default date/calendar classes in Java and I'm just getting myself in a mess.

Thanks,
S

Edit: How silly of me, apologies for not adding my code :(

```
public static List<Date> getDaysInRange(Date startdate,
                                      Date enddate,
                                      Date checkDate) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
   List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   cal.setTime(startdate);

   while (cal.getTime().before(enddate)) {
      if (sdf.format(cal.getTime()).equals(sdf.format(checkDate))) {
        Date result = cal.getTime();
        dates.add(result);
      }
      cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   }
  return dates;
}
```

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're not here to do your job for you. You show what you've written, we'll maybe try help fix it.

Comment: Added my code so far, I think it kind of works but just feels a bit clunky to me :(

Comment: Method works for me. What's the problem?

Comment: Evidently I have been getting myself more confused than necessary. As long as there is nothing glaring from a performance pov that I could improve, I'm putting this question down to my hangover. Thanks to all for the input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Date-Only

Since you want only a date without time-of-day and without time zone, use a date-only class. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes lack such a class. And those old classes are notoriously troublesome and flawed.

Instead use either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), built into [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), inspired by Joda-Time.

## Joda-Time

Here is some untested code using Joda-Time 2.6.

The main idea is to focus on the small set of possible year numbers rather than test every day of year. In the example below, that means six date-time values to compare rather than thousands. Besides efficiency, the purpose of the code becomes more apparent.

The arguments to your routine should be a month number and a day-of-month number, a pair of ints or Integers, rather than a Date. As seen in this examples two int variables, `month` and `day`.

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate( 2011, 2, 3 );
LocalDate stop = new LocalDate( 2016, 4, 5 );
int yearStart = start.getYear();
int yearStop = stop.getYear();
int month = 11;
int day = 22;

for ( i = yearStart, i <= yearStop, i++ ) 
{
    LocalDate x = new LocalDate( i, month, day );
    boolean matchStart = ( x.isEqual( start ) || x.isAfter( start ) );
    boolean matchStop = x.isBefore( stop ); // Half-Open approach where beginning of range is inclusive while ending is exclusive.
    if ( matchStart && matchStop ) 
    {
        // Add to collection of LocalDate objects.
        // Later you can ask each LocalDate object for its day-of-week.
    {
}
```

## java.time

The java.time package also offers a `LocalDate` class. The code would be similar to the above Joda-Time example.

Answer (score 0):

I think using SimpleDateFormat is a bad idea. Use Calendar for comparison directly, like this

```
cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```